# Django order_by('?') filter with distinct()

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to retrieving unique foreign key instances and ordering randomly
However, I got an error when I want to use order_by('?')

My query is like this:

```
qs=Course.objects.distinct('courseschedule__object_id').order_by('courseschedule__object_id')
```

this query is works fine, but right now I want to order randomly(to get random result every time),I try this

```
qs=qs.order_by('?')
```

I got this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Any idea how to fix it? My database is Postgres,  I don't want do rawSQL.... I really appreciate you guys help!!!!

Comment: Relevant: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17990

Answer (score 0):

First of all, random order using the database is expensive and slow according to: [querysetsDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) . Second, in my opinion instead of using the database to return a random order get your query from the database without distinct (because it also can be slow), shuffle the query using python methods for example: [randomOrder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and make a set() and then . This way you are not using the database to do your stuff but using pure python code.

Comment: Sure, but I think that using the backend is more efficient then using the database. I didn't do any time testing. Just guessing.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment, I'm an idiot and commenting too early in the morning (mixed order and sampling).

Comment: Ok, no worries, :)

Comment: The 2 do often overlap since people use random order + limit for random sampling, but this question seems different, now that I took the time to read it properly.

Comment: I knew random order using the database is expensive , but this function is in the ListAPIView, I have to return the queryset.... otherwise , I have to override all the filters that my teammate already wrote before, I do not want do that.. so any idea how to do that by using the queryset. Thanks!!!!!